# Walls are distorted during rendering

Tags: rendering

I can not understand the reason why the walls are distorted in the render mode.

Please help me understand my mistake

[image]

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the geometry. Go to edit mode of the wall object and inspect it. You should check the shader as well.

Comment: It looks as if you may have duplicate overlapping faces. Select All in Edit mode then hit 'M' > Merge by Distance and see if any vertices are deleted from the brief message which will appear in the middle of the bottom status bar.

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/